# Recursion stops after some executions

Tags: c

I am trying to find the largest prime factor of a number. The code stops working (at least I think like that) after some executions. `printf` parts are for debugging.
The number is 600851475143.

```
long recursed(long i, long j){
  if (j == 1){
    return i;
  }
  else if (i%j != 0){
    printf("Else if i : %ld %ld\n", i, j);
    return recursed(i, j-1);
  }
  else{
    i /= j;
    printf("Else i : %ld\n", i);
    return recursed(i, i-1);
  }
}
```

Comment: Maybe stackoverflow ? try with smaller number.

Comment: What values are you running the function with to get the issue? Please post an example that people can just copy and paste to see what's wrong instead of making them guess how the function is supposed to be used.

Comment: [mcve] please. We see what you're calling, but not *how* you're calling it. This is missing the driving `main()`. And the "printf parts" are probably important, including the first few and last few and total numbe rof perceived executions. And of course, *debuggers* are literally *made* for this. Also, unless this is being compiled on x64 (you never say), 600851475143 breaches most `long` implementations (which usually are equivalent to `int`, and tap out at 2147483647).

Comment: Does it work for small inputs?

Comment: How does it handle negative inputs? What is `sizeof(long)` in your system? I suggest you to start using `<stdint.h>`

Comment: Considering that the recursion is called with `i-1` or with `j-1` that's an awful lot of recursion to factorize `600851475143`.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please **edit your question** using the `edit` button below the tags and include information regarding the parameters passed to your routine and any errors you're receiving. Thanks.

Comment: Well you create unsafe recursion and this overload  your stack memory.
Better change this to interation. (`while`)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A typical 32-bit long tops out at 4,294,967,295.
You gave it 600,851,475,143, which is much much larger.

Be sure you compile on x64, and use `unsigned long long`.
Then check for overflows.